# Use the keyword 'Internet' or 'internet' in our publications?

Tags: publications, writing, writing-style, technology

So far all research papers I read and wrote I used the word 'Internet' instead of 'internet'. I did see an online article about the fact that people are using 'internet' more often nowadays, so should we still keep using it as before?

**My Take**: the word 'Internet' is a name, that represents a technical infrastructure of many layers (networks, computers, programs, etc.) and its many users as a whole. So I think, the keyword 'Internet' should always be written with capital I. Am I wrong here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I believe that it is not specifically about academia, and should be migrated to English.SE.

Comment: If you mean "keyword" in the sense of words or phrases associated with the article by authors and/or editors to make the article easier to find and categorize, then I think it doesn't matter since keyword searches are often case-insensitive.

Comment: I recently read an article (on Slashdot?) that the Internet has officially become internet.

Answer (score 3):

People don't agree on this please see this wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization_of_%22Internet%22) on the capitalization of the word "internet".